# Setting Cell Editable Property to a JTable row on the fly

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, jtable

I have a table say `Table-C` which gets row data by dragging from `Table-A` or `Table-B.` If the row is dragged from `Table-A` to `Table-C` then that row is not editable and it should be of a specified color. If a row is dragged from `Table-B` to `Table-C` then that row has only some specified columns as editable and that row is shown in another color.  I cannot set `isCellEditable` for some specified rows in `Table-C` because I cannot control the place where user drops the row on `Table-C.` My first part of the task was that I should be able drag data  which I am able to do successfully. But my second part is that I have to give that `isCellEditable` property and `color` to these rows on the fly depending on the table it is from .. this is the part where I am stuck. Any ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to supply a marker in the row data that the table model can identify the rows you don't want to edited, this marker could also be used by the renderers.

One way would be to wrap the incoming row data in a wrapper class as its dropped onto the table, this way you could seed the wrapper with what ever information you wanted/needed

Comment: +1 .. Okay as far as I understood .. it means in the isCellEditable method I should get marker of the current row and then basing on the marker I should return either true or false. But what is the place that marker should be .. can I insert another column (which is not shown in the table) that I can use for storing the marker.

Comment: It depends how your model is set up. If each row is represented by a single object, you could create special wrapper object, which contains the row object and provides the extended functionality you're wanting. This means you need to use instanceof to determine how to handle each row. If your using arrays, you could include additional elements beyond the number of columns which can be filled with these markers

Comment: Yep, mine is single object for each row .. So I create a wrapper object which contains both row object and my marker .. ? is that rt ..

Comment: Yep.  In your model, you will need to use instanceof when getting the value to determine if it's a wrapper object or not (and your cell renderer).